# MarkLogic - lexicon expansion not working as expected

Tags: marklogic, cts-search

I'm trying to address the issue of excessive incorrect results from an unfiltered search with a wildcard.

In my understanding, the right way to fix it is to use "lexicon expansion."

However, when I look at the documentation for `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery()`, I only see options for lexicon-expansion-limit and limit-check/no-limit-check. Nothing to turn lexicon expansion on or off.

Apparently it’s not doing lexicon expansion (if I understand it correctly) because when I do a wildcarded search with `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery`, it gives lots of spurious results.  And since the default lexicon-expansion-limit is 4096, it’s fewer than the 3066 terms that `cts.ValueMatch()` returns for this query.

So I don’t get why it’s not working.

I can do it explicitly by running `cts.valueMatch()` and using the result of that as the search term(s) but wasn’t that the point of lexicon expansion?

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?